# How does the property RegularExpression work in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have some code:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->

Set oWebEdit = Browser("").Page("").WebEdit("")
'Get the TOProperties collection
Set TOProps = oWebEdit.GetTOProperties()
Dim i, iCount
iCount = TOProps.Count - 1
'Loop through all the properties
For i = 0 To iCount
    'Get Name of the property
    sName = TOProps(i).Name

    'Get the value of the property
    sValue = TOProps(i).Value

    'Is the value a regular expression
    isRegularExpression = TOProps(i).RegularExpression

    'Display the values
    Msgbox sName & "->" & sValue & "->" & isRegularExpression
Next
```

My question: when I add an object to the Object Repository (OR) manually (eg: from Google search page: webButton search), I see its `name`, `type`, and `htmltag` as properties in the OR.

How, in this piece of code, is `isRegularExpression` taken into consideration?  How does this expression get answered?  Are there any other properties which are not visible in the OR but can be found out?

Answer (score 2):

You can change whether the value of a property is treated as a regular expression from the object repository by first clicking the  checking the **Configure the value** button of the property

[image: Configure the value]

Then check the **Regular expression** checkbox

[image: Regular expression]

---

**Note:** The OP asked why the `RegularExpression` is `True` by default. I checked and it appears that for Win32 objects (I checked `Window` and `WinButton`) we get `False` while for Web objects (I checked `Browser`, `Page` and `WebEdit`) we get `True`. This appears to be a defect in QTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Motti . You are my savior :)

Comment: it shows true for all the properties even before i checked the regex option in the config for those properties. all the properties can be made reg ex enabled and also is it true by default.

Comment: @NidhiPrasad I'm updating my answer please have a look.